# Mongoose MVC - TypeError: ItemModel is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, model-view-controller, mongoose

I'm trying to follow MVC pattern by defining/exporting a model, and using this model in the controller. However, I'm getting an error: TypeError: ItemModel is not a constructor.

I've followed several other examples and am unable to see why this error is occurring.

The file structure is as follows:

src\db_test.js

src\controller\Item.js

src\models\Item.js

```html
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "name": String
});

var ItemModel =  mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
module.export = ItemModel;
```

controller\Item.js

```html
var ItemModel = require('../models/Item');

var itemController = {};

itemController.save = function(obj) {
    
    var model = new ItemModel(obj); // Error here
    model.save(function(err, item) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Failed to save');
            return;
        }
        console.log('saved successfully!');
    });
}

module.exports = itemController;
```

db_test.js

```html
const ItemController = require('./controller/Item');

var testItem = {
    "name": "ItemName"
};

ItemController.save(testItem);
```

Output:

```html
\src\controller\Item.js:18
    var model = new ItemModel(obj); // Error here
                ^

TypeError: ItemModel is not a constructor
    at Object.itemController.save (\src\controller\Item.js:5:4)
    at Object.<anonymous> (\src\db_test.js:7:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a missing letter.

Item.js

```
module.export = ItemModel
```

change

```
module.exports = ItemModel
```